# How to send a message to the console but return nothing instead of NULL after checking condition in R

Tags: r, error-handling

This is probably a duplicate, but I was unable to find a relevant question. Basically, I would like to send a message a to the console after some condition and return "nothing". In addition, I am trying to understand and make sense of when/if `message()` returns a `NULL`:

```r
foo_01 <- function(bar = NULL) {
  if (is.null(bar)) {
    message("Error: please provide a value for bar.")
    return()
  }
}

foo_02 <- function(bar = NULL) {
  if (is.null(bar)) {
    msg <- message("Error: please provide a value for bar.")
    return(msg)
  }
}

foo_03 <- function(bar = NULL) {
  if (is.null(bar)) {
    return(message("Error: please provide a value for bar."))
  }
}

foo_01()
#> Error: please provide a value for bar.
#> NULL
foo_02()
#> Error: please provide a value for bar.
#> NULL
foo_03()
#> Error: please provide a value for bar.
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

1. Desired output would be `foo_03()`, but is this the best way to get there?
2. Why are `foo_02()` and `foo_03` different?
3. Is `invisible` relevant here?

I am aware of `stop()`, but would prefer the "cleaner" output from `message()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`message` is not cleaner -- if your code wants to raise an error it should use `stop` to do that.  Also you can detect a missing argument using `missing`.

```
foo2 <- function(bar) {
  if (missing(bar)) stop("please provide a value for bar")
  bar
}
foo2()
```

Instead of `return(x)` you can use `return(invisible(x))` to return `x` but not display it (or if it is the last statement run then just `invisible(x)` is sufficient).